# Trix editor: how to know when attachment upload finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, trix, actiontext

When using ActionText, `f.rich_text_area` renders a Trix editor. When I add an attachment to the editor, it starts direct-uploading automatically. If I submit the form before the upload is complete, the attachment will be missing in the text, obviously. I know that the event `trix-attachment-add` is triggered when an attachment is *just added*, before the upload starts. **What event listener can I add in order to know when the upload is *finished*?**

Comment: I also could not find an end event. The ActiveStorage 'direct-uploads:end' event looked promising, but ActionText does not hook into the ActiveStorage events.  I ended up doing  this: `const contentEmpty = !content || !content.length || content === '<div></div>';` in order to prevent submissions before attachments were added, though this only works for the first attachment.  I considered parsing the raw content for blob ids, but wasn't worth it for me. I bet they'd be open to a pr adding more events out of the box for ActionText.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Stimulus.js, the following controller will disable the submit button until all attachments are done uploading.

Controller:

```
// form-with-trix-controller.js
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['submit']

  disableSubmitIfTrixAttachmentsUploading(/*event*/) {
    const { hasTrixAttachmentsUploading } = this
    this.submitTargets.forEach(submitTarget => submitTarget.disabled = hasTrixAttachmentsUploading)
  }

  get hasTrixAttachmentsUploading() {
    return this.trixAttachments.some(attachment => attachment.isPending())
  }

  get trixAttachments() {
    return this.trixElements.flatMap(trix => trix.editor.getDocument().getAttachments())
  }

  get trixElements() {
    return Array.from(this.element.querySelectorAll("trix-editor"))
  }
}
```

In your form that wrapps a Trix controller:

```
<form data-controller="form-with-trix" data-action="trix-change->form#disableSubmitIfTrixAttachmentsUploading">  
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save File" data-form-target="submit">
</form>
```

Based on code from Hey.com.